# Is the set $S$ of all smooth functions on $B_1$ whose normal derivative vanishes along the boundary $\partial B_1$ dense in $C^0 (B_1, \Bbb C)\ $?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, contest-math, uniform-convergence, smooth-functions

> Let $B_1 : = \{z \in \Bbb C\ |\ |z| \leq 1 \},$ and let $C^0(B_1,\Bbb C)$ be the space of continuous complex valued functions on $B_1$ equipped with the uniform convergence topology. Let $S$ be the set of all smooth functions $f : B_1 \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ such that the normal derivative of $f$ vanishes along the boundary $\partial B_1.$ Is $S$ dense in $C^0 (B_1, \Bbb C)\ $?

If $f \in S$ then what is meant by saying that the normal derivative of $f$ vanishes on the boundary $\partial B_1\ $? I think it means $\frac {\partial\ \mathfrak Rf} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial\ \mathfrak R f} {\partial y} = 0$ and $\frac {\partial\ \mathfrak I f} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial\ \mathfrak I f} {\partial y} = 0$ on $\partial B_1.$ If it is the case then how does it imply denseness of $S$ in $C^0(B_1,\Bbb C)\ $? Any help or suggestion is very much required at this moment.

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ NBHM PhD Screening Test $2020.$

Comment: @David C. Ullrich gradient is defined for a scalar function. How do I define gradient of a vector valued function? Do you mean Frechet derivative?

Comment: The normal derivative would be the directional derivative along the vector normal to $ \partial B _ 1 $. At a point $ z = x + i y $ on $ \partial B _ 1 $ (so that $ | z | = \sqrt { x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 } = 1 $), the tangent vector would be $ t ( z ) = - y + i x = i z $ and the normal vector would be $ n ( z ) = x + i y = z $. Therefore, the normal derivative is
$$ D _ { n ( z ) } f ( z ) = \lim _ { \substack { w \to 0 \\ w \ \propto \ n ( z ) } } \frac { f ( z + w ) - f ( z ) } w = \lim _ { \substack { h \to 0 \\ \Im h = 0 } } \frac { f ( z + h z ) - f ( z ) } { h z } \text . $$